# TypeError: rstrip arg must be None or str: Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I run my code I get this

> TypeError: rstrip arg must be None or str

here is my code:

```
words = input("Words: ")
wordcount = len(words)
tweet = str(words)
x = 0
while wordcount <= 140:
    phrase = input("Words: ")
    tweet = tweet+' '+str(phrase)
    wordcount = len(tweet)
    print(wordcount)
    print(tweet)
    x = len(phrase)+1
    if wordcount >= 140:
        break

tweet = tweet.rstrip(x+1)
wordcount = len(tweet)
print(wordcount)
print(tweet)
```

Note: this is in python 3

any help?

Comment: What do you think `rstrip` does?

Comment: What do you expect `tweet.rstrip(x+1)` to do?

Comment: Or more to the point; do you think `x+1` is None or a string?

Comment: well, if x is len(tweet), then shouldn't it strip the length of x+1 off tweet?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want: `tweet = tweet[:140].rstrip()` to make sure it's only ever 140 chars or less? eg: slicing instead of stripping minus any trailing spaces...

Answer (score 3):

You are passing an `integer` to `rstrip`, you must pass `None` or some character, if this character is what you want to remove from the right-hand side of the string.

Example:

```
'   aaab      '.rstrip()
#'   aaab'

'   aaabcccccc'.rstrip('c')
#'   aaab'
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds like you want to "strip the length `x+1` off tweet". To do that, you can use string slicing. `My_String[a:b]` will give you a new string with the characters from character number `a`, to character number `b-1`. If you leave either side empty, it will go to that end of the string (ie. `My_String[a:]` will go from `a` to the end of the string). To go from the **end** of the string, use a negative number. Your code should look like:

```
tweet = tweet[:-x]
```